# more parameters with mail() function

Tags: php, forms, email, parameters

Ive been trying to find a place to help me with this, but most answers I get come up confusing, or they don't work out very well.

I want to have a mail function that sends over 8 pieces of information, but when I include all that I get a warning that says the max amount allowed is 5 and I have too many. Is there a way to bypass this?

This is the code im currently using:

```
mail('kyle-*****@sbcglobal.net', $subject, $comments, $from, $parent, $child, $address, $number);
```

Comment: Put your information in the message portion of the email.

Comment: You need to construct your message body to contain the information you want, then send that info as the email text - not by simply appending variables to the `mail()` function.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just invent parameters and expect a function to magically understand what to do with them.

Per the docs, `mail()` takes the following:

- `$to`
- `$subject`
- `$message`
- `$additional_headers` (optional)
- `$additional_parameters` (optional)

I presume `$comments, $from, $parent, $child, $address, $number` are data you want in the e-mail. If so, you need to construct a *single* string out of them to be used as your message. Something like:

```
$message = "Comments: $comments\n\n";
$message .= "From: $from\n\n";
$message .= "Parent: $parent\n\n";
$message .= "Child: $child\n\n";
$message .= "Address: $address\n\n";
$message .= "Number: $number\n\n";
```

then call `mail('kyle-*****@sbcglobal.net', $subject, $message);`